# Angular Jasmine test : Unable to test the click event of the button for material table

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing a code in angular test file to test click of Material dialog button. When I run my test , I get error Cannot read property 'triggerEventHandler' of null

```
 const setupComponent = () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CountryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  };

  beforeEach(() => {

    mockXYZApiServiceApiService = new Mock<XYZApiService>({
      getCountries: () => of(countryGridDataModel)
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule ],
      declarations: [CountryComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: XYZApiServiceApiService,
          useFactory: () => mockXYZApiServiceApiService.Object,
        }

      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

     fit('should call the mat dialog open On View click', fakeAsync(async () => {
        setupComponent();
        fixture.debugElement
          .query(By.css('#btnViewCountry'))
          .triggerEventHandler('click', {});
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug, ensure that `#btnViewCountry` is present and not hidden by an `*ngIf`.

```
 fit('should call the mat dialog open On View click', fakeAsync(async () => {
        setupComponent();
        // add this log to output the whole HTML and ensure that
        // #btnViewCountry is present
        console.log(fixture.nativeElement);
        fixture.debugElement
          .query(By.css('#btnViewCountry'))
          .triggerEventHandler('click', {});
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }));
```

Comment: The log doesn't contain the html and indeed very little html, that i am looking for and my guess is that this is triggering before the elements are even rendered. There isn't any ngIf statement in my html code

Comment: I tried this and it still didnt work     setTimeout(() => {
      fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.css('#btnViewCountry'))
      .triggerEventHandler('click', {});
      fixture.whenStable();
    }, 5000);

Comment: I would look for an `*ngIf` blocking `#btnViewCountry` and the spelling of `#btnViewCountry` in the HTML and if `#btnViewCountry` is in a child component, you have to render the child component as well.